# convert function to partial function scala

Tags: scala, akka, case, actor, partialfunction

I have a sealed trait:

```
sealed trait ActorMessage
case class AddX(x: Int) extends ActorMessage
case class RemoveX(x: Int) extends ActorMessage
```

Also I have a function to handle all messages and warn me about non exhaustive match:

```
def handleMessage: ActorMessage => Unit = {
  case AddX(x) => ...
  case RemoveX(x) => ...
}
```

Actor requires a PartialFunction[Any, Unit]. PartialFunction extends Function which means I can't assign my Function to be PartialFunction.

I have written simple converter:

```
def liftToPartialFunction[FUND <: PFUND, B, PFUND](f: Function[FUND, B]): PartialFunction[PFUND, B] = new PartialFunction[PFUND, B] {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: PFUND): Boolean = x.isInstanceOf[FUND]
  override def apply(v1: PFUND): B = f(v1.asInstanceOf[FUND])
}
```

But is there a better way to do this? Or is there any equivalent in standard scala library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
override def receive = {
  case m: ActorMessage => m match {
    // You'll get non-exhaustive match warnings here
    case AddX(x) => /* ... */
    case RemoveX(x) => /* ... */
  }
  case m => /* log a warning */
}
```

Equivalently, using your `handleMessage` function:

```
override def receive = {
  case m: ActorMessage => handleMessage(m)
  case m => /* log a warning */
}
```

Comment: Last example is probably what I will stick to but maybe do know if I could make
my receive function to look like this:
def receive = handleMessage orElse handleEvent orElse ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Function.unlift` -

```
val f: Throwable => Option[String] = {
  case e: NullPointerException => Some("nah it's ok")
  case e => None
}

Future(null.toString).recover(Function.unlift(f))
// Future(Success(nah it's ok))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just declare `handleMessage` as a partial function:

```
def handleMessage: PartialFunction[ActorMessage,Unit] = {
    case AddX(x) => ...
    case RemoveX(x) => ...
}
```

Comment: This won't warn me about non-exhaustive match.